# Finding Projection onto $\textrm{im}(A)$ along $\ker(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ such that $A^2 = A$.

> If $\textrm{rank}(A) = 1$, then show that the linear transformation $T(x) = Ax$ is the projection onto $\textrm{im}(A)$ along $k(A)$, where $k(A)$ is the kernel of $A$.

I don't know what the question is asking, namely, what is a projection onto $\textrm{im}(A)$ *along*  $k(A)$? Second, I'm not sure what we are projecting. $x$? $Ax$? I assume it is $x$.

So the questions reads: show that the linear transformation $T(x) = Ax$ is the projection of $x$ onto $\textrm{im}(A)$ along $k(A)$. Again, I don't know what this means. I know what it means to say $x$ is a projection onto something, but not a projection onto something *and* along something else.

Comment: You may wish to give a look at the Wikipedia page on [projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Properties_and_classification).

Answer (score 0):

Have you drawn a picture to help out, say with $A = \begin{bmatrix}1 &-2\\-2 &4\end{bmatrix}$?

In this example, we can see that

$$\operatorname{Im} A = \operatorname{Span}\left(\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ -2\end{bmatrix}\right).$$

Now if you look at where the point $(3, 2)$ gets sent by $A$, its "path" isn't perpendicular to $\operatorname{Im}(A)$, which would be the case for the standard (orthogonal) projection onto $\operatorname{Im}(A)$.

[image]

So, based on the picture here, can you guess what it means to project *along* $\ker A$? More importantly, do you think you can prove what you think it means?